# How can i detect VPN login on Windows Server via C#

Tags: c#, vpn

How do I write a listener for VPN logging on Windows Server? I would like to write an application that alerts me every time someone VPN's into my Windows Server. I was able to write code that listen to Server logins. So I would like to write code like this, but for VPN logins:

```
protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription e)
{ 
                switch (e.Reason)
                {
                    case SessionChangeReason.SessionLock:
                                    break;
                    case SessionChangeReason.SessionLogon:
                           break;
                    case SessionChangeReason.SessionUnlock:
                           break;
                    case SessionChangeReason.ConsoleConnect:
                           break;
                    case SessionChangeReason.ConsoleDisconnect:
                          break;

                    case SessionChangeReason.RemoteConnect:
                         break;

                    case SessionChangeReason.RemoteDisconnect:
                         break;
                }

}
```

Comment: What is the VPN service? What have you tried? Is there an API for the service?

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins Can you elaborate what you mean by VPN service ? I'm using Peap method to secure my VPN. I searched all over then net, i could not find any article that talks about VPN listeners, they only talk about authenticating VPN login details, not listening to VPN connections on the server.

Comment: Are using a radius server, Cisco VPN, or built in Windows Server VPN or ??? Using Windows VPN if you have implemented security audit logging you can probably read the event logs.

Comment: I'm using a built in Windows Server VPN. I will read from the event logs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows VPN here are two options you can use.

By default, log files are kept in `%windir%\system32\Logfiles\RRAS`. You can parse the log files there. They will have 4 lines per session: username, logon time, and IP address. Logoff will be the 4th entry when it occurs. You can change the logging directory using RRAS MMC > Properties > Logging.

The other option is you can use [`EventLog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entries.aspx) using and look for [`RRAS Audits`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315788(v=ws.10).aspx) entries  whit will have `Log` set to `Security` with `Source`  set to `RemoteAccess`. View the documentation for other properties to decide which ones you want.

You can enumerate all entries:

```
EventLog log = EventLog.GetEventLogs()
    .First(o => o.Log == "Security" && o.Source=="RemoteAccess");

foreach (EventLogEntry entry in log.Entries)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\tEntry: " + entry.Message);
}
```

Optionally, you can add event handler for real time monitoring:.

```
private void Log_EntryWritten(object sender, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
{
    string message = e.Entry.Message;
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}


public void MonitorVPNLogs()
{
    EventLog log = EventLog.GetEventLogs()
        .First(o => o.Log == "Security" && o.Source=="RemoteAccess");

    log.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    log.EntryWritten += Log_EntryWritten;
}
```

Comment: i had issues implementing your code. I fixed the issue by using FileSystemWatcher library. This library watch the vpn log files, and sends us a notification if the files are changed.

Comment: My first suggestion worked then. Good to see you found a working solution.

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you.